# Understanding Sylvester' s $1871$ paper of primes in arithmetic progression of the forms $4n+3$ and $6n+5$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

The following is the proof of infinitude of primes in arithmetic progression of the form $4n+3$ and $ 6n+5$ done by Sylvester in $1871$ in his paper "On the theorem that an arithmetical progression which contains more than one, contains infinite number of primes number." The screenshot is from the book /note "The collected mathematical papers Of James Joseph Sylvester".

I having difficulty in understanding the proof in the case $4n+3$ .
I would be highly grateful if someone helps me in understanding the proof for the case $4n+3.$

This question has also been asked in [math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362091/understanding-sylvester-s-1871-paper-of-primes-in-arithmetic-progression-of-t) since it was not answered by the time it was posted in math over flow.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me first prove that the number of primes is infinite. This can be achieved using the identity
$$  x = \sum_{d \ge 1} \mu(d) \frac{x^d}{1-x^d} , $$
where $\mu$ denotes the Moebius function.

If there are only finitely many prime numbers $p_1$, $\ldots$ , $p_n$, then no integer larger than $N = p_1 \cdots p_n$ can be squarefree, hence $\mu(d) = 0$ for all $d > N$ but $\mu(N) \ne 0$. But then the function on the right has a pole in $x = e^{2\pi i/N}$, whereas the polynomial on the left is entire. This is a contradiction. I am sure that there are more clever ways of obtaining such a contradiction.

The identity used for proving that there are infinitely many primes $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ is
$$   \sum_d x^d = \sum_m \mu(m) \frac{x^m}{1-x^{2m}}, $$
where the sum on the left is over all odd natural numbers $d$ not divisible by any prime $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, and the sum on the right is over all odd integers $m$ not divisible by any prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

Assume that there are only finitely many primes $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$. Then the sum on the right is finite, and the last nonzero term occurs when $m$ is equal to the product of all these primes. Setting $x = i$ we find $i^m = +i$ or $-i$ according as $m$ has an even or an odd number of prime factors, hence $i^m = \mu(m) \cdot i$ and $i^{2m} = (-1)^m = -1$. Thus
$$ \sum_m \mu(m) \frac{i^m}{1-i^{2m}} = \frac i2 \cdot M, $$
where $M$ is the number of nonzero terms on the right.

On the other hand, since the number of primes is infinite, there must be infinitely primes $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, hence the left hand side is unbounded as $x \to i$. This is a contradiction.

Again I am certain that there are more clever ways of exploiting these identities to prove the infinitude of primes.